# Minimum time between typhoid vaccine and prednisone treatment?

Tags: vaccination, steroids, typhoid

Having recently completed the [typhoid oral vaccine series](http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-9755/vivotif-berna-vaccine-oral/details#interactions) (live attenuated), I note that one of the described drug interactions are corticosteroids. What is the nature of this drug interaction - is it simply that the immunosuppression reduces the effectiveness of the immune response to the vaccine?

How many days following the completion of the vaccine series should one wait at minimum before taking prednisone (high dose, tapering), in order to maintain the efficacy of the vaccine and prevent side effects? I am unable to find a great deal of information in the literature about this drug interaction.

<sub>NB: The doctor seemed unconcerned about this; however, I would still like to know more about the nature and timescale of this drug interaction.</sub>